# Should I start a new Django Project in Python 3 or Python 2.7?

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have been using Django 1.8 and Python 2.7 for a couple of projects and they're working fine. I am about to start a new project and I am wondering whether I should use Python 3 for my Django project. Is it recommended that I should use Python 3? What are the benefits of using Python 3 over 2.7

Comment: This is off-topic, but the answer is Python 3. Python 2 is end-of-life, everything is switching over sooner or later.